# SBT Build error with AKKA conflict

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

The project I am referring has following `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "esc-index"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo/"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.3.10",
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.8" % "test"
  )
}
```

When in execute sbt compile, I get the following error.

```
$ sbt compile
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\AnandKrishnan\Documents\GitHub\esc\index\project
[info] Set current project to esc-index (in build file:/C:/Users/AnandKrishnan/Documents/GitHub/esc/index/)
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/AnandKrishnan/Documents/GitHub/esc/index/}index...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/C:/Users/AnandKrishnan/Documents/GitHub/esc/index/}index:
[error]    com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor <none>, _2.11
java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at sbt.ConflictWarning$.processCrossVersioned(ConflictWarning.scala:46)
        at sbt.ConflictWarning$.apply(ConflictWarning.scala:32)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$66.apply(Defaults.scala:1164)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$66.apply(Defaults.scala:1161)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Jan 4, 2016 8:48:19 AM
```

I did `sbt clean` before `sbt compile`. I also tried excluding akka like this  `.exclude("com.typesafe.akka", "akka-actor_2.11")` with no luck.

Comment: Could you please try from a new directory what I posted into my answer?

Comment: Can you list the directory's content (using `tree` or similar)? What other files do you have in the project? Do you perhaps have `project` directory? What's inside? What other `*.sbt` files do you have in the main directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried from a new directory `/tmp/aaa` succesfully:

```
$ cat > build.sbt
name := "esc-index"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo/"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.3.10",
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.8" % "test"
  )
}
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/filippovitale/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/filippovitale/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to esc-index (in build file:/private/tmp/aaa/)
> compile
[info] Updating {file:/private/tmp/aaa/}aaa...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/typesafe/play/play_2.11/2.3.10/play_2.11-2.3.10.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play_2.11;2.3.10!play_2.11.jar (5094ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/typesafe/play/build-link/2.3.10/build-link-2.3.10.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.3.10!build-link.jar (908ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/typesafe/play/play-iteratees_2.11/2.3.10/play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.10.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-iteratees_2.11;2.3.10!play-iteratees_2.11.jar (2011ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/typesafe/play/play-json_2.11/2.3.10/play-json_2.11-2.3.10.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.11;2.3.10!play-json_2.11.jar (1872ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/netty/netty/3.9.9.Final/netty-3.9.9.Final.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] io.netty#netty;3.9.9.Final!netty.jar(bundle) (2119ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/typesafe/play/play-exceptions/2.3.10/play-exceptions-2.3.10.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.3.10!play-exceptions.jar (842ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/typesafe/play/play-functional_2.11/2.3.10/play-functional_2.11-2.3.10.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-functional_2.11;2.3.10!play-functional_2.11.jar (1927ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/typesafe/play/play-datacommons_2.11/2.3.10/play-datacommons_2.11-2.3.10.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#play-datacommons_2.11;2.3.10!play-datacommons_2.11.jar (850ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/novocode/junit-interface/0.8/junit-interface-0.8.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.novocode#junit-interface;0.8!junit-interface.jar (1066ms)
[info] downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] junit#junit;4.8.2!junit.jar (1795ms)
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 33 s, completed 04/01/2016 2:31:04 PM
```

Comment: Thank you Filippo, do you mean, copy the entire project in to another folder and try again?

Comment: I mean just the `build.sbt` file in an empty dir then try `sbt compile`

Comment: The problem was due to the conflicting version for Scala and Play. The one in SBT dependencies and in the actual code were not matching as the code was written long time back and the dependencies only were updated to latest version.

Comment: I could make it work by specifying the java version to java 7 instead of 8 which was forcing me to change all the dependencies to new which caused the above error. sbt -java-home /c/"Program Files"/Java/jdk1.7.0_79